# Angular Build For MultiProject Workspace

Tags: angular-cli

I have a angular project workspace which consist of multiple projects and library.

```
...
e2e
projects
   authentication-project
   vendor-project
   customer-project
   shared-library 
angular.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

When I build project I get a get coupled of hashed file with minified content.

Is their a way i can tell cli to to bundle the project build with specific project-prefix with hash file names so that only specific project bundle needs to replaced without impacting other project bundle files.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the build command with specific project name.

Example: `ng build vendor-project`.

Editing the `angular.json` will give you more control on the hash names and other options. If you want more control then you can always write your own npm scripts or  `eject` the project and access the underlying webpack config . 
Also, have a look at `Nx` workspaces if required. https://nx.dev/

Comment: They way I am trying put the build such that....
Their is one master project which is being importing features from other sub-projects...A build to this project is complete clean build but for a hot deployment a specific project needs to build and bundle file for that specific project should be get replaced on server so that existing features should not get impacted.

Comment: Eject can might give possibility..something to be explore...but is their any easy and straight way to achieve it?